# .count() is deprecated but .countDocuments() has an issue

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which contains >20M documents and growing. For reporting purposes I want to query for the total number of documents in the collection.

`db.collection.count()` immediately returns a value, but .count() is deprecated and .countDocuments() is recommended.

`db.collection.countDocuments({})` also returns the value, but it takes minutes to execute (5-10 minutes in my case)

The same experience is true when using the .Net driver. .Count() and .CountAsync() both return a value immediately but .CountDocuments and .CountDocumentsAsync() take minutes.

Comment: What about `estimatedDocumentCount`?

Comment: Use [estimatedDocumentCount](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/index.html)

Comment: That works! Thank you Ayush and Wernfried

Comment: How about this: `db.collection.stats().count` ?